# how to invoke particular sibling methode in angular 2

Tags: angular

```
from first component i want to call second component methode. 

export class FirstComponent {
            constructor(private _service: CommonService) {}
            }
```

this is second component... wihtout using constructors of onngInit methodes.

```
 export class SecondComponent {
          constructor(private _service: CommonService) { }

          callMyMethod(){

          }
        }
```

Comment: Here you can use angular services.

Comment: from service how can i invoke methode

Comment: You can make a common method that can be used in both components.

Comment: i know this but problem is i just want to invoke secondComponent methode directly

Comment: could u plz give me a demo

Comment: You can see here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reoqec?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You can import second component and using the instance of component can access method

here's is example

`first.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SecondComponent } from '../second/second.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-first',
  templateUrl: './first.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./first.component.css'],
  providers: [SecondComponent]

})
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public second: SecondComponent) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.second.getMessage());
  }

}
```

`first.component.html`

```
<p>
    welcome <b>{{second.getMessage()}}</b>
</p>
```

`second.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-second',
  templateUrl: './second.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./second.component.css']
})
export class SecondComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  getMessage(){
    return "This is second component";
  }

}
```

here is [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcvv6p?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffirst%2Ffirst.component.ts) demo.